# Sitecore Log reports an issue: Error during Aggregation

Tags: xdb, reporting

Sitecore log recently reported an error during aggregation. While going through the log file, found an exception below:

> Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Message: T-SQL ERROR
>   242, SEVERITY 16, STATE 3, PROCEDURE (null), LINE 474, MESSAGE: The
>   conversion of a datetime data type to a smalldatetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. Source: .Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()   at
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderTransaction.Dispose()   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2()
>   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.ExecuteNoResult(Action
>   action, Action recover)   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.Store(Guid
>   id, AggregationDataSet data)   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Platform.SwitchingReportingStorageProvider.Store(Guid
>   id, AggregationDataSet data)

Please suggest, what should be the possible reason for this kind of error?

Comment: Please provide few more information - 
Is this upgraded solution?
Are you using WFFM or any other module?
Version of Sitecore?

Comment: Hi @MahendraShekhawat , Sitecore version 8.0 update 3. Yes I'm using WFFM module.

Answer (score 4):

There is KB article for similar problem, The may occur when a contact submits a particular web form created using the WFFM module two or more times.

Please see below link - 
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/282795

and there is good blog as well by Chaturanga - https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.in/2015/06/sitecore-8-wffm-data-aggregation-error.html

You can try these solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra Shekhawat.But in my WFFM form there are no such field like convert date-time related like this.

Comment: I am not sure but analytics data required some date-time conversation.

Comment: Hello @Mahendra what is the SItecore Reporting Database means? Is it the analytics.secondary database or any other database. Please suggest.

Comment: In simple the reporting database contains aggregated data from the xDB collection database or in general it is actual analytics database visible in the sitecore reports.
And a secondary reporting database works as secondary to avoid disruption during the rebuild process, it store all aggregated data as it is reprocessed.